# Snowflake - Recursion exceeded max iteration count (100)

Tags: recursion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
WITH recursive T1(USER_NAME,ID, PARENT_ID, LVL, ROOT_ID, PATH) AS (
-- ANCHOR MEMBER.
SELECT USR_NM,USR_NO,
      MNGR_EMPLY_NBR PARENT_ID,
      1 AS LVL,
      USR_NO AS ROOT_ID,
      TO_CHAR(FRST_NM || ' ' || LST_NM) AS PATH
FROM    EMPLOYEE

UNION ALL

-- RECURSIVE MEMBER.
SELECT T2.USR_NM,T2.USR_NO,
        T2.MNGR_EMPLY_NBR  PARENT_ID,
      LVL+1,
      T1.ROOT_ID,
      T1.PATH || '|' || T2.FRST_NM || ' ' || T2.LST_NM AS PATH
FROM   EMPLOYEE T2 , T1
WHERE  T2.MNGR_EMPLY_NBR = T1.ID
)
select * from T1
```

While running the above code I'm facing Recursion exceeded max iteration count (100) in snowflake. Can anyone guide me with a solution for this or is there any way to re-write this code without recursion?

Answer (score 1):

This is standard infinite recursion protection.
You can read about it here: [Potential for Infinite Loops](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html#potential-for-infinite-loops)

You must submit a request to Snowflake Support to increase the limit and enter how many.

Referring to the documentation:

> In theory, constructing a recursive CTE incorrectly can cause an infinite loop. In practice, Snowflake prevents this by limiting the number of iterations that the recursive clause will perform in a single query. The MAX_RECURSIONS parameter limits the number of iterations.

> To change MAX_RECURSIONS for your account, please contact Snowflake Support.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is about to be removed as part of 2022_02 change bundle.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Hierarchical-Data-Queries-Iteration-Limits-No-Longer-Enforced

Here is the pending behaviour change log: https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Pending-Behavior-Change-Log

> 2022_02
>
> Disabled by default in 6.7 (Mar 9-10); can be enabled for testing
>
> Planned to be enabled by default in March

Comment: Thanks, Tomas Fejfar. May I know when 2022_02 change bundle will be implemented from the snowflake side?

Comment: Is there any way to make this code work out without recursive ?

Comment: That's irrelevant as the limit that caused the error will be lifted. It can be lifter right now if you enable the bundle in your accoutn (see the Pending behavior log on how to do that)